# Fold a list but alternate used functions

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, functional-style

Is there a clean way to fold a list but alternate functions used?

Say we call such function `FoldAlternating`. Then for example,

The `FoldAlternating[{Plus,Times}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]]` would produce `235`,

Because it is equivalent to `Times[Plus[Times[Plus[Times[Plus[1, 5], 2], 3], 3], 2], 5]`.

---

**Edit:** For $2$ functions `f,g` and starting value `v_: 1`, I can do it recursively:

```
fa[f_, g_, list_, v_: 1, i_: 1] := 
 If[i + 1 == Length[list], f[g[v, list[[i]]], list[[i + 1]]], 
  If[i == Length[list], g[v, list[[i]]], 
   fa[f, g, list, f[g[v, list[[i]]], list[[i + 1]]], i + 2]]]
```

where `fa[Times, Plus, {5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]` gives the expected example from above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
ClearAll[foldRotate]
foldRotate = Module[{fl = #}, Fold[Last[fl = RotateLeft[fl]]@## &, ##2]] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
foldRotate[{Plus, Times}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]
```

> ```
>  235
> ```

```
foldRotate[{Plus, Times}, 1, {5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]
```

> ```
>  235
> ```

```
foldRotate[{foo, bar, fum}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
```

> ```
> foo[fum[bar[foo[a, b], c], d], e]
> ```

Comment: Clever! Very nice indeed.

Comment: Thank you @MarcoB.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this:

```
ClearAll[foldAlternating];
foldAlternating[{f1_, f2_}, lst_] := Fold[
    {First@#1 + 1, Replace[First@#1, {_?OddQ :> f1, _ :> f2}]@@{Last@#1, #2}} &,
    {1, First@lst}, Rest@lst
] // Last;

foldAlternating[{Plus, Times}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]
(* 235 *)
```

It would be easy enough to generalise such a function.

## EDIT

In fact, here is a generalisation:

```
ClearAll[foldAlternating];
foldAlternating[fnsLst_, lst_] := Fold[
    {Mod[First@#1 + 1, Length[fnsLst]], (fnsLst[[First@#1 + 1]])@@{Last@#1, #2}} &,
    {0, First@lst}, Rest@lst
] // Last;

foldAlternating[{Plus, Times}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5}]
(* 235 *)

foldAlternating[{Plus, Times, Mod}, {1, 5, 2, 4}]
(* 0 *)

foldAlternating[{Plus, Times, Mod}, {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5, 7, 10, 9}]
(* 8 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple loop? (I know  we are not supposed to use loops in Mathematica, but unless it is very inefficient, I do not see problem myself using loops)

```
foldAlternating[f_, g_, lst_] := Module[{z, n},
   z = f[lst[[1]], lst[[2]]];
   op = g;
   Do[
    z = op[z, lst[[n]]];
    op = If[op === f, g, f]
    , {n, 3, Length@lst}
    ];
   z
   ];
```

To use it

```
lst = {1, 5, 2, 3, 3, 2, 5};
foldAlternating[Plus, Times, lst]
(*235*)
```

Note, this assumes `lst` is at least 3 elements long. Easy to add error checking if needed.

ps. do not name your own functions starting with UpperCaseLetter so not to confuse them with Mathematica's own functions, unless they are inside your own package.